# Error 166 Unable to copy file "obj\x86\Debug\FileName.exe" to "bin\Debug\FileName.exe"

Tags: .net

Suddenly began to get this error when I try to Build a project:

> Error 166 Unable to copy file
>   "obj\x86\Debug\ObjectRecognitionDriver.exe"  to
>   "bin\Debug\ObjectRecognitionDriver.exe". The process cannot access the
>   file 'bin\Debug\ObjectRecognitionDriver.exe' because it is being used
>   by another process.

Any idea what cause to this error and how to solve it?

Comment: Did you try manually cleaning your obj and bin folders?

Comment: Have you checked in the Task Manager if the _ObjectRecognitionDriver.exe_ is still running?

Comment: I try to clean project and solution,but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any idea what cause to this error

Like the error says:

> The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\ObjectRecognitionDriver.exe' **because it is being used by another process.**

---

> and how to solve it?

Restarting Visual Studio usually solves this. What have you tried?

Using the tool [Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) you can find out which process is locking the file.